# Is there a convenience for safe dereferencing in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators, dereference

So perl5porters is discussing to add a safe dereferencing operator, to allow stuff like

```
$ceo_car_color = $company->ceo->car->color
    if  defined $company
    and defined $company->ceo
    and defined $company->ceo->car;
```

to be shortened to e.g.

```
$ceo_car_color = $company->>ceo->>car->>color;
```

where `$foo->>bar` means `defined $foo ? $foo->bar : undef`.

**The question:** Is there some module or unobstrusive hack that gets me this operator, or similar behavior with a visually pleasing syntax?

For your enjoyment, I'll list ideas that I was able to come up with.

1. A multiple derefencing method (looks ugly).

   ```
   sub multicall {
       my $instance = shift // return undef;
       for my $method (@_) {
           $instance = $instance->$method() // return undef;
       }
       return $instance;
   }

   $ceo_car_color = multicall($company, qw(ceo car color));
   ```
2. A wrapper that turns `undef` into a proxy object (looks even uglier) which returns `undef` from all function calls.

   ```
   { package Safe; sub AUTOLOAD { return undef } }
   sub safe { (shift) // bless {}, 'Safe' }

   $ceo_car_color = safe(safe(safe($company)->ceo)->car)->color;
   ```
3. Since I have access to the implementations of `ceo()`, `car()` and `color()`, I thought about returning the safe proxy directly from these methods, but then existing code might break:

   ```
   my $ceo = $company->ceo;
   my $car = $ceo->car if defined $ceo; # defined() breaks
   ```

   Unfortunately, I don't see anything in `perldoc overload` about overloading the meaning of `defined` and `//` in my safe proxy.

Comment: Number 2 wins the prize for the weirdest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most useful solution, but it's one more WTDI (a variant of nr. 1) and it's a non-trivial use-case for [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil)'s **reduce**, which are very rare. ;)

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature     'say';
use List::Util  'reduce';

my $answer = 42;
sub new { bless \$answer }
sub foo { return shift }        # just chaining
sub bar { return undef }        # break the chain
sub baz { return ${shift()} }   # return the answer

sub multicall { reduce { our ($a, $b); $a and $a = $a->$b } @_ }

my $obj = main->new();
say $obj->multicall(qw(foo foo baz)) // 'undef!';
say $obj->multicall(qw(foo bar baz)) // 'undef!';
```

### Output

```
42
undef!
```

*Note:*

Of course it should be

```
return unless defined $a;
$a = $a->$b;
```

instead of the shorter `$a and $a = $a->$b` from above to work correctly with defined but false values, but my point here is to use **reduce**.

Comment: Making multicall a member of $obj makes the syntax quite likeable, actually. And the doc becomes discoverable for someone who stumbles across this in a large codebase.

Comment: I'm now going with this solution, though I'll probably write calls like `$obj->multicall(foo => bar => baz =>)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`:

```
$ceo_car_color = eval { $company->ceo->car->color };
```

But it will of course catch any errors, not just calling a method on an `undef`.